# Spring boot schema.sql not working with mysqldump file

Tags: java, mysql, spring, unit-testing

Spring boot automatically picked up and ran my **schema.sql** file everytime my integration test is started.

Issue is:
It gives me an error

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

I am able to import this file with `mysql` command without problem, so I suspect that Spring boot is not using `mysql` command to run the script.
**schema.sql** is created by **mysqldump**. Nothing is modified.
It works after I did the following "workaround":
1. Get rid of MySQL specific keywords/commands like  `/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;`
2. re-arrange the `create table` blocks so that the tables are created in the right order to avoid the foreign key constraint errors.

**Question**:
How to make Spring boot to import my **schema.sql** file like **mysql** does? It would be nice if I can just `mysqldump` the file and use it for testing instead of using some "hacky workarounds".

Thank you!

Comment: I have an assumption that the problem might be related to `autocommit` parameter, that is `true` for Spring and `false` for MySQL CLI.

Comment: @RomanProshin could you please elaborate on that? `autocommit` as in **spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit**?

Comment: Well, I think `spring.datasource.auto-commit` is more suitable. Or just try both variants.

Comment: @RomanProshin I tried. Unfortunately, it isn't working. I could not find any official doc/resources that talk about this issue.

Comment: Finally you can try to create datasource manually and in this case you control all parameters of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the beginning of your .sql file

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and in the end

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

The command disables foreign keys checks and restores it back.

Dump just inserts all the table's content rows but related table is not inserted yet.

MYSQL restoring from dump has the lines automatically.

Comment: thanks for your help, +1. So to the answer is no, there is no way for spring boot to import the mysql dump file generated from `mysqldump` command before test without some manual changes?

Comment: I am not sure... it could be MySQL dump creation has some options to set/restore the constraints check. But for the case all you need is to add two more lines in the SQL one in the beginning and one in the end.